# Is there a way to Include underscores when using word movements (<e>, <b>, <w>) VSCode VIM?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I am always frustrated when using move keys such as `e`, `b` or `w` in python variables or strings that are separated with underscores, due to the fact, that instead of stopping in the last/next underscore, it stops and the start/end of the string/variable

Is there a way to Include underscores when using word movements (`e`, `b`, `w`)?

Comment: is there a way to set the word-character-set, or can you change the commands bound to `b` or `w` to `cursorWordEndRight` and `cursorWordLeft`

Comment: What would be the settings inside vscode settings.json? And what would be the correct values? @rioV8

Comment: if the vim extension uses the VSC commands it is determined by the word characters defined in the language definition